# Exiting vbscript terminates foreground threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, vbscript, interop

I have a project that provides interop libraries that a person could use when authoring a vbscript file (such as importing data from a custom data source).

In one particular call, an underlying c# library kicks off a thread to write event data. We want the data to be written asynchronously (this was done for different reasons; the interop libraries just use the event-writing feature) and create the threads as a Foreground threads to prevent the process from terminating until they are finished.

The problem is when running the *.vbs file, the process runs to completion and exits. Any foreground threads in progress are terminated before completing.

Is this termination of foreground threads when a *.vbs file completes normal expected behavior?

I also reproduced the scenario in a c# console application which terminates with Environment.Exit(0), which closes foreground threads as normal behavior. Exiting the console app with a return statement will only allow termination once all foreground threads have terminated.

Comment: How do you exit the vbscript code?

Comment: Double-click *.vbs file, let it run it's for-loop to completion.

Comment: OK, guess I didn't read your question good enough. No, there's nothing you can do about this. VBScript has no control or knowledge of your threads that you have started. You will have to provide a way for the VBScript code to signal to the interop class(es) that it's done and intends to terminate, so that the class(es) can correctly flush data and terminate the threads before the VBScript program finally terminates.

Comment: The code that waits until those threads terminate in a .NET program is built into the framework, there's nothing in those threads that forces the program to stay alive, it's the framework around that waits for them to complete. So you need to build the same kind of structure in your VBScript code.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. We don't want the VBScript to require additional housekeeping for this issue so I've adjusted how the interop code calls the event-writing methods so that they're processed synchronously.
Async isn't required for the interop but is when running in our UI. But I wanted to understand how VBS handles threading compared to the framework.

Comment: In that case I would reverse the framework in such a way that it does what you said in the last comment. I would make the classes support both asynchronous and synchronous usage, but default to synchronous, and have to be specifically asked to convert to asynchronous usage (or perhaps have a specific way to construct/initialize them in this case) so that the same objects support both worlds.

Comment: I've posted my comments as an answer as well.

Comment: Agreed. I try to follow Task Asynchronous Pattern and author methods such as 'DoStuff' and 'DoStuffAsync', allowing the caller to decide which to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET framework is responsible for waiting for those foreground threads when the main thread exits (normally) and not as you've found, by forcibly terminating the process.

VBScript has no such framework for this particular thing, at least not to handle, or know anything about, .NET threads constructed from COM objects it uses.

As such, VBScript is completely oblivious to your threads and will happily tear down the process when it thinks it is the right time, which will in turn forcibly terminate your threads before they're done.

There's a couple of ways to handle this:

1. Add housekeeping calls to your VBScript code that will inform the COM objects that the process is about to terminate, so that those COM objects have a chance to clean up properly, by terminating those threads and flushing any pending data.
2. Change your COM objects to not use threads and write/flush all data synchronously.
3. Combine 1. and 2. in such a way that your VBScript code can specifically ask those COM objects to use threads, and thus have to inform them of termination, defaulting the COM objects to synchronous behaviour unless told otherwise.